# App that is a viewer and editor for the same data type?

Tags: cocoa, nsdocument

The NSDocument system is primarily for files that read and write a particular data type.  What about a type that needs to be both read-only and read-write?  I'm planning an e-mail app; it would need a read-write document type for composing messages before sending, and a read-only type for reviewing already sent messages (from a Sent Items folder).  The Mail.app works like this.

Would this be done as two NSDocument subclasses?  (They would use the same RFC822 class for their model class.)  How would you make one document type read-only?

Answer (score 0):

It's still one document. You just have a different UI that you display for editing. 
In the case of email you would only display editing from New or Reply/Reply All/forward action methods. (Quoting the original mail as appropriate. )
You could technically go and open the "read only" mail file in any editor that can open the file.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way would be to create one `BOOL saying`isReadOnly`.

If its value is `YES`(readonly mode) make the `NSTextView` readonly, if it is `NO`(edit mode) make it default one i.e, read & write enabled.

The following will work as per your `BOOL isReadOnly;` value

```
[self.yourTextView setEditable:isReadOnly];
```